# powershell dictionary of arrays - dynamically table-format output

Tags: powershell

So here's what I'm trying to do...
basically i have a dictionary of arrays

```
$data = @{
    "123" = @('ABC',
        'DEF',
        'GHI'
)       
    "234" = @(
        'JKL',
        'MNO',
        'PQR'
    )
    "345" = @( 
         'STU',
         'VWX',
         'YZ'
    )
}

$serverArray = @('one', 'two', 'three')
```

If I do this...

```
 $alignment = @()
 $alignment += @{label="Type";Expression={$_.name};alignment="left"}
 $alignment += @{label=$serverArray[0];Expression={$_.value[0]};alignment="left"}
 $alignment += @{label=$serverArray[1];Expression={$_.value[1]};alignment="left"}
 $alignment += @{label=$serverArray[2];Expression={$_.value[2]};alignment="left"}
 $data.GetEnumerator() | sort name | Format-Table $alignment -autosize
```

I get the correct desired output.

```
    Type   one    two    three
    123    ABC    DEF    GHI
    234    JKL    MNO    PQR
    345    STU    VWX    YZ
```

What I was trying to do though is make it so that no matter the length of my $serverArray it would format with the appropriate columns.

So I tried a few different variations (using for loop and foreach) to this but nothing seems to work ...

```
$alignment = @()
$alignment += @{label="Type";Expression={$_.name};alignment="left"}
for([int]$s=0; $s -lt $serverArray.length; $s++) {    
    write-output $s
    $alignment += @{label=$serverArray[$s];Expression={$_.value[$s]};alignment="left"}
}
$websites.GetEnumerator() | sort name | Format-Table $alignment -autosize
```

Seems like since the expression is being stored - it's storing $s literally instead of the actual value that it represents at the time.

How can I make it store the actual value in the expression for $s (0, 1, or 2) instead?

Ideally I could have a serverArray of "one, two, three, four, five" and since it's in a loop everything work just the same.

Any suggestions? Greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the evaluation of $s in the creation of the expression part of the hash table which takes it literally instead of its value.

I'd try this:

```
for([int]$s=0; $s -lt $serverArray.length; $s++) {    
    $scr = [scriptblock]::Create('$_.value['+$s+"]")
    $alignment += @{label=$serverArray[$s];Expression=$scr;alignment="left"}
}
```

Comment: thanks - worked like a charm! Didn't know you could create scriptblocks...i bet that comes in handy from time to time!